# Authorize.net iOS sdk

Tags: ios, authorize.net

I have created the token using [this link](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-ios)

Now how can I charge user using this token? No proper info is available anywhere.

Comment: You can't charge user from your app. Authorized.net provide `curl` code, that code need to be implement from API Side. You just have to pass that generated token, amount, and other required parameter.

Comment: where I can find that api documentation @Kuldeep

Comment: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/

Comment: You can see how to submit a transaction from your server here: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Using_the_Payment_Nonce_in_an_API_Request_From_Your_Server